# is it recommended to use PreparedStatement.setBoolean(1, Boolean.TRUE) in java?

Tags: java, jdbc, boolean

Could you help me to figure out what is the best practice between `PreparedStatement.setBoolean(1, Boolean.TRUE)` and `PreparedStatement.setBoolean(1, true)`?

Comment: Keep it simple, use `setBoolean(1, true)`, I don't think there's much of a difference.

Comment: If I'm correct `PreparedStatement.setBoolean(1, Boolean.TRUE)` needs to do unboxing, and because of it is worse performance-wise

Comment: @Amongalen that has zero effect on performance.

Comment: i found this in java doc "The driver converts this to an SQL BIT or BOOLEAN value when it sends it to the database". so it is better to use Boolean.TRUE

Comment: @radhwenhrizi - No, that doesn't have any effect on what type you should use with the `setBoolean` function. By the time `setBoolean` is using the value, it's a `boolean` no matter what you use when calling it, because (again), it accepts a `boolean`, not a `Boolean`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both work, but note that [`setBoolean`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setBoolean(int,boolean)) accepts a `boolean`, not `Boolean`. [`TRUE`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Boolean.html#TRUE) is a `Boolean` (a wrapper object around `true`). There's no reason to use the wrapper with `setBoolean`, it just gets auto-unboxed to a `boolean` via the [`booleanValue`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Boolean.html#booleanValue()) method. Use `true`, not `Boolean.TRUE`, unless you have a strong style reason for using an unnecessary wrapper object.

---

In a comment you've said:

> i found this in java doc "The driver converts this to an SQL BIT or BOOLEAN value when it sends it to the database". so it is better to use Boolean.TRUE

No, the SQL type that gets used by the driver doesn't have anything to do with this. It has to do with what the `setBoolean` method signature says. The method signature says it accepts a `boolean`, so that's what it will see. The only reason using `Boolean.TRUE` works is that **before** calling `setBoolean`, the compiler outputs code to call `booleanValue()` on `Boolean.TRUE` to get its equivalent `boolean` value (`true`). In fact, this:

```
ps.setBoolean(1, Boolean.TRUE);
```

and this:

```
ps.setBoolean(1, Boolean.TRUE.booleanValue());
```

produce **identical** bytecode, which looks something like this:

```
21: getstatic     #6         // Field java/lang/Boolean.TRUE:Ljava/lang/Boolean;
24: invokevirtual #7         // Method java/lang/Boolean.booleanValue:()Z
27: invokeinterface #8,  3   // InterfaceMethod java/sql/PreparedStatement.setBoolean:(IZ)V
```

Better to use

```
ps.setBoolean(1, true);
```

so there's no need for that extra call (although it will get optimized away fairly quickly if needed).

Comment: i found this in java doc "The driver converts this to an SQL BIT or BOOLEAN value when it sends it to the database". so it is better to use Boolean.TRUE

Comment: @radhwenhrizi - See [my reply here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58955617/is-it-recommended-to-use-preparedstatement-setboolean1-boolean-true-in-java/58955667#comment104167162_58955617).

Answer (score 8):

Since `Boolean.TRUE` is of type `Boolean`, and

```
void setBoolean(int parameterIndex, boolean x) throws SQLException;
```

requires a `boolean`, it makes more sense to use `setBoolean(1, true)`, to avoid unnecessary unboxing.

Comment: i found this in java doc "The driver converts this to an SQL BIT or BOOLEAN value when it sends it to the database". so it is better to use Boolean.TRUE

Comment: @radhwenhrizi: it doesn't matter what the driver does with the value afterwards. The fact that the parameters takes a primitive `boolean` means that if you passed a `Boolean` instead it would need to be unboxed first. So directly passing `boolean` when you have the choice is clearly better.